# How to capitalize first letter in strings that may contain numbers

Tags: python, string, capitalization

I would like to read through a file and capitalize the first letters in a string using Python, but some of the strings may contain numbers first. Specifically the file might look like this:

```
"hello world"
"11hello world"
"66645world hello"
```

I would like this to be:

```
"Hello world"
"11Hello world"
"66645World hello"
```

I have tried the following, but this only capitalizes if the letter is in the first position.

```
with open('input.txt') as input, open("output.txt", "a") as output:
    for line in input:
        output.write(line[0:1].upper()+line[1:-1].lower()+"\n")
```

Any suggestions? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
for line in output:
    m = re.search('[a-zA-Z]', line);
    if m is not None:
        index = m.start()
        output.write(line[0:index] + line[index].upper() + line[index + 1:])
```

Comment: Issue with using [a-z] only would be that it can match alphabet which might not be the first alphabet in the string (if the first alphabet is already in upper case).

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Yeah I wasn't being super formal, but there's a lot of error checking that can go into this answer to make it more robust.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function with a `for` loop:

```
x = "hello world"
y = "11hello world"
z = "66645world hello"

def capper(mystr):
    for idx, i in enumerate(mystr):
        if not i.isdigit():  # or if i.isalpha()
            return ''.join(mystr[:idx] + mystr[idx:].capitalize())
    return mystr

print(list(map(capper, (x, y, z))))

['Hello world', '11Hello world', '66645World hello']
```

Comment: This would work if there is no case where the first alphabet comes after a space.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal, Yup, this doesn't require any splitting. So it should work provided `str.isdigit` is acceptable for OP's user case.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to reverse the condition and use `string.isalpha()` instead?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal, Not sure what's more efficient. In *most* cases, though not all, they'll be equivalent. Can you give an example where it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expression to find the position of the first alphabet and then use `upper()` on that index to capitalize that character. Something like this should work:

```
import re

s =  "66645hello world"
m = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]', s)
index = m.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
import re

text = "1234hello"
index = re.search("[a-zA-Z]", text).start()
text_list = list(text)
text_list[index] = text_list[index].upper()

''.join(text_list)
```

The result is: `1234Hello`

Answer (score 1):

May be worth trying ...

```
>>> s = '11hello World'
>>> for i, c in enumerate(s):
...     if not c.isdigit():
...         break
... 
>>> s[:i] + s[i:].capitalize()
'11Hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first alpha character and capitalize it like this:

```
with open("input.txt") as in_file, open("output.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        pos = next((i for i, e in enumerate(line) if e.isalpha()), 0)
        line = line[:pos] + line[pos].upper() + line[pos + 1:]
        out_file.write(line)
```

Which Outputs:

```
Hello world
11Hello world
66645World hello
```

Comment: This, in my opinion, is preferable to regex.

Comment: @jpp wouldn't this allow non-alphabets also? This is checking for digits only.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Good point. Changed it to ignore everything but letters.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, for example:

```
import re

re_numstart = re.compile(r'^([0-9]*)(.*)')

def capfirst(s):
    ma = re_numstart.match(s)
    return ma.group(1) + ma.group(2).capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with open('input.txt') as input, open("output.txt", "a") as output:
for line in input:
    t_line = ""
    for c in line:
        if c.isalpha():
            t_line += c.capitalize()
            t_line += line[line.index(c)+1:]
            break
        else:
            t_line += c
    output.write(t_line)
```

Execution result:

```
Hello world
11Hello world
66645World hello
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a one-line REGEX approach, but using `title()` should also work:

```
def capitalise_first_letter(s):
    spl = s.split()
    return spl[0].title() + ' ' + ' '.join(spl[1:])

s = ['123hello world',
"hello world",
"11hello world",
"66645world hello"]


for i in s:
    print(capitalise_first_letter(i))
```

Producing:

```
Hello world
11Hello world
66645World hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for that:

```
import re

line = "66645world hello"

regex = re.compile(r'\D')
tofind = regex.search(line)
pos = line.find(tofind.group(0))+1

line = line[0:pos].upper()+line[pos:-pos].lower()+"\n"

print(line)
```

output: `66645World`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is already a lot of answers, that should work.

I find them overly complicated or complex though...

Here is a simpler solution:

```
for s in ("hello world", "11hello world", "66645world hello"):
    first_letter = next(c for c in s if not c.isdigit())
    print(s.replace(first_letter, first_letter.upper(), 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `title()` method will capitalize the first alpha character of the string, and ignore the digits before it. It also works well for non-ASCII characters, contrary to the regex methods using `[a-zA-Z]`.

From the doc:

> str.title()
>
> Return a titlecased version of the string where words
>   start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are
>   lowercase. [...] The algorithm uses a simple language-independent
>   definition of a word as groups of consecutive letters. The definition
>   works in many contexts but it means that apostrophes in contractions
>   and possessives form word boundaries, which may not be the desired
>   result:

We can take advantage of it this way:

```
def my_capitalize(s):
    first, rest = s.split(maxsplit=1)
    split_on_quote = first.split("'", maxsplit=1)
    split_on_quote[0] = split_on_quote[0].title()
    first = "'".join(split_on_quote)

    return first + ' ' + rest
```

A few tests:

```
tests = ["hello world", "11hello world", "66645world hello", "123ça marche!", "234i'm good"]
for s in tests:
    print(my_capitalize(s))

# Hello world
# 11Hello world
# 66645World hello
# 123Ça marche!  # The non-ASCII ç was turned to uppercase
# 234I'm good    # Words containing a quote are treated properly
```

Comment: By the way, `title()` breaks on any punctuation, not just contractions.

Answer (score 0):

With [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and *repl* as a function:

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.

```
def capitalize(m):
    return m.group(1) + m.group(2).upper() + m.group(3)

lines = ["hello world", "11hello world", "66645world hello"]
for line in lines:
    print re.sub(r'(\d*)(\D)(.*)', capitalize, line)
```

Output:

```
Hello world
11Hello world
66645World hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Using isdigit() and title() for strings:

```
s = ['123hello world', "hello world", "11hello world", "66645world hello"]
print [each if each[0].isdigit() else each.title() for each in s ]


# ['123hello world', 'Hello World', '11hello world', '66645world hello']
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert the strings starting with a character but not to capitalize the characters after a digit, you can try this piece of code:

```
def solve(s):
    str1 =""
    for i in s.split(' '):
        str1=str1+str(i.capitalize()+' ') #capitalizes the first character of the string
    return str1

>>solve('hello 5g')
>>Hello 5g
```

Comment: This won't work for "123adf asdf". Expected answer is "123Adf Asdf".

Comment: @SRIDHARAN didn't you see what I wrote before the code? I wanted to achieve exactly what you've just mentioned. I wanted to capitalize each word THAT STARTS WITH A CHARACTER but keep others lowercase if they do not start with a CHARACTER.

Comment: but the question asked above didn't need that. Please see the examples posted above.